# Put Strings into RTF-Format

Tags: java, encoding, io, rtf

I want to generate a RTF-Document with my program. I use an `RTFEditor` which gives me the edited text in a rtfformat, but I also have `TextFields` and I should take Strings from the TextFields into the RTF Documeent. I have tried to edit the rtf document text, but i got this annoying encoding problem with ANSI and UTF-8 i think.
If my TextFields got strings with an "äöüß" ... and so on i get this encoding stuff like "Ã¶"
My target is to get a good looking RTF-Document without encoding-issues.

What is the best way to handle this issue?

Here is my class which outputs the rtf document: 
NOTE: Please focus into the important things in this code. I hope the german terms in my code dont confuse you :).

```
/**
 * Handles the Saving of a Protokoll to a .rtf file.
 * The .executeSaving() method executes the process of saving.
 * @author me
 */
public class WordExport {

    // other methods...

    /**
     * Executes the saving-progress by the given file.
     * Structure of the rtf-File:
     * -------------------------
     * HeadString               |
     * -------------------------
     * Content                  |
     * ..                       |  
     * ..                       |
     * ..                       |
     * ..                       |
     * -------------------------
     * @param file points to the target where the .rtf should be saved.
     * @param protokoll The protokoll which you want to save.
     * @throws IOException Thrown when something is not okay with the IO.
     */
    public void executeSaving(File file, Protokoll protokoll) throws IOException
    {
        //I want to insert my HeaderString into a specific position so i have to split etc...
        String content = new String();
        content = protokoll.getInhalt();
        String[] split = content.split("}", 3);
        for(int i = 0; i < split.length ; i++)
        {
            if(!split[i].contains("}"))
            {
                split[i] += "}";

            }
        }

        String teilnehmer = new String();
        for (Profil p : protokoll.getTeilnehmer())
        {
            teilnehmer += p.toString() + "\\par\n ";
        }
        String headString = new String();
        //HERE IS THE IMPORTANT CODE --> here i put my strings bare into the rtf-format and i dont know how to handle the encoding.
        headString = "\\f1\\fs44\\i0\\b0\\ul\\cf1\\ "+ protokoll.getTitel() +" \\par\n" +
                  "\\par\n" +
                  "\\fs24\\ul0 Raum: "+ protokoll.getRaum() +"\\par\n" +
                  "Zeitraum: "+ protokoll.getZeitraum() +"\\par\n" +
                  "Datum: "+ protokoll.getErstellungsdatum().toString() +"\\par\n" +
                  "\\par\n" +
                  "Teilnehmer: \\par\n" +
                  teilnehmer +
                  "\\ul0\\par ";

        split[2] = headString+ split[2];

        //Converts the String[] from above to the string, which you need to write into the .rtf file.
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for(String s : split)
        {
            builder.append(s);
        }
        content = builder.toString();
      if(!file.exists())
      {
           file.createNewFile();
      }
      FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
      BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
      bw.write(content);
      bw.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: OT, but important and related: You should use English for identifiers and comments in your code. You never know when you will have to share your code with the world. English will make communication and collaboration much easier then. Also you will get better at writing English.

Comment: its one of my first projects and your point is one of my first things i will do on my next project.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ISO-8859-1` encode. This encode format will support that characters too.

Answer (score 0):

I hate character encodings... I believe the following blog might help you [here](http://blog.stuartlewis.com/2010/09/18/java-rtf-and-unicode-characters/)

i will post the code here just in case that site has issues in the future though, NOTE I DID NOT WRITE THIS NOR DO I TAKE CREDIT.

```
// Create a hashtable to hold the characters to convert
Hashtable<String, String> replace = new Hashtable<String, String>();

// The String to convert
String str = "The Māori Macron";

// Values we'll use in the loop
int value;
String bit;
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    // Get the character value
    bit = str.substring(i, i + 1);
    value = str.codePointAt(i);

    // If the character value is above the
    // 7-bit range of RTF ASCII
    if (value > 127) {
        replace.put(bit, "\\\\u" + value + "\\\\'  ");
    }
}

// Now replace all the characters we found
Enumeration e = parameters.keys();
String key, value;
while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
    // Get the key
    key = (String)e.nextElement();

    // Get the value
    value = (String)parameters.get(key);

    // Make the substitution
    str = str.replaceAll(key, value);
}
```

Comment: the link and the example are good but i dont understand what "x" in the code is. The declaration is missing.

Comment: I think that is probably supposed to be s

Comment: i replaced x with s but now i dont know what "parameters" are. not mentioned anyway. Sorry for asking but without more information this code does not work and i can not autocomplete it.